# Any arguments for bpy.ops.file.autopack_toggle()?

Tags: scripting

I'm trying to pack all additional files with the .blend file so my material properties don't change when I move my files to other directories.

Could anybody let me know if bpy.ops.file.autopack_toggle() needs any arguments? That alone is not working.

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is not working? The [API](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.file.html) says that there are no arguments needed. Do you get any error messages when executing the command? Go to *Window* => *Toggle System Console* to get the console to show and look for errors there.

Comment: @palkonimo as it usually happens with blender, the code works when used in the console (it packs the 2 files). When I use the same line.

Comment: @palkonimo I'm not sure what you mean by "Toggle System Console" I have the script in python and I run the python file using a terminal window (with: blender --background --python name.py). The message I get is: "Info: No new files have been packed"

Comment: Then everything appears to be working fine. There are just no new files added to the .blend file and thus Blender cannot pack new files. Try adding a new image that has not been used before in the project to any material and then execute the script again. Now there should be a different message along the lines of "Info: 1 new file has been packed". And the terminal window is what I meant by "Toggle System Console", I just explained the way of getting it to show up from Blender's UI.